# Accessing the Windows notification center from Java

Tags: java, windows, push-notification, notifications

Windows 8 introduced a new os-native notification center called "Action Center".

I wanted to know if there is any way of accessing it from Java without of using JNI.

Comment: If there is any command line tools for this, you can call with with `exec`

Comment: I can't find a command line tool with access to it. But there might be a way to access it from PowerShell.

Comment: If you want to show notifications look there:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34490485/5509049

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Windows Notification in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490218/how-to-make-a-windows-notification-in-java)