# Set a desktop notification at the specified date

Tags: java, swing, notifications, desktop-application, system-tray

I'm working on creating a desktop application for my college project using Java and NetBeans 8.2 IDE with MySQL database as back end and Windows as my OS.

I set an auto-generated ID, take some title, note, and a date as my input. It gets stored in my database. I want to set a desktop notification; the notification pops up at the input date. The user must get notified at the input date, the notification displaying my title and note. I saw [JCommunique](http://www.java2s.com/example/jar/j/download-jcommunique200jar-file.html) jar which is really nice but seems to me that it doesn't allow to set time input based notifications.
I'm unable to source any reference as mostly every Notification related reference is of Java Android and not of Java Desktop.

(If possible, get a Windows notification, popping from right generally (doesn't matter much)).

Edits : This [tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490218/how-to-make-a-windows-notification-in-java) here is a nice option, but setting a feature such that it pops out at the specified date is the real requirement.)

Comment: Run a Java task on startup, check the database, create a tray note if today's the day.

Comment: You're right! Thanks. It should work.